# Finding width and height from htmlstring in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to search a string containing some html for a iframe. I will need to find the width and height.

string example:

```
var stringEx = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/spr0ZHC2x2o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a jQuery object by doing:

```
var $iframe = $('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/spr0ZHC2x2o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

Then you can use `.attr()` to grab the `width` and `height` attributes:

```
var width = $iframe.attr('width'),
    height = $iframe.attr('height');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kuqajelo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: there is a note here about the type of the returned `width`, it's a string, so we may need to convert it to number if needed.

Comment: Not to belabor this issue, but I ran it in jsperf (http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-jquery) against my "killing unicorns" regex string parsing answer below. Regex is over 150 TIMES FASTER. But you all use whatever you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringEx = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/spr0ZHC2x2o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
var w = stringEx.match(/width="(\d+)"/),
    h = stringEx.match(/height="(\d+)"/);

if (w) w = w[1]; // "560"
if (h) h = h[1]; // "315"
```

Comment: This will match the `marginwidth` and `marginheight` attributes as well, in an arbitrary `iframe` string. [Use `\b` to match word borders](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Also, the double-quotes around the numbers are optional, and spaces may exist around the equals sign. `/\bwidth\s*=\s*"?(\d+)"?/` should do it. This is why [you shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/901048).

Comment: I parsed a string. A string representing a single html element, yes, but a simple string nonetheless. That's no indication that the string is fetched from some external place, nor even that it's beyond his/her control. I'm comfortable using this technique (and do) for situations like this. I'm a killer of unicorns. Give me different/more parameters and I'll give a different/less-acid-inducing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
var stringEx = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/spr0ZHC2x2o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

var width = /width="(\d+)"/.exec(stringEx)[1]; //looks for a match in the stringEx string
var height = /height="(\d+)"/.exec(stringEx)[1];

console.log(width); //560
console.log(height); //315
```

NOTE: If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array. 
    The returned array has the matched text as the first item, 
    and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text
    that was captured